# find path between two pointt

Tags: java, mysql

hi all i have a database that hold array of points frompoint topoint distance, 
look like {1 2 5, 2 3 4 , 3 4 2}
im geting the data to

```
        List<Conniction> tempDeal = ConnictionDAO.getInstance().findAll();
```

and then iterate its information to Lists

```
List<String> oneid = new ArrayList<String>();
 List<String> twoid = new ArrayList<String>();
 List<String> size = new ArrayList<String>();
 for(Conniction obj: tempDeal){
     if(obj!=null) {

             oneid.add(obj.getOneid());

             twoid.add(obj.getTwoid());
             size.add(obj.getSize());
```

now i need to find the distance between point 1 to point 3 its should be 9
which function should i build

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: no code, please post some code

Comment: Have you already took a look into Dijkstra algorithm?

Comment: yes i look in Dijkstra algorithm , but i cant get it to work from my data

Comment: Could you explain in more detail what your data looks like?

Comment: lets say like that i attempt to work with many Dijkstra algorithms to calculate the distance(size) but in all cods the path are manual written and i want to find the path from points when the path didn't given

Comment: Dijkstra only needs the edges and their weights. Do you mean you do not know the edges?

Comment: yes i dont understand how to insert the edges

Comment: The edges should be given otherwise there is no graph structure. If there are no edges, you cannot find the shortest path between two nodes. This is why I asked what information you have given.

Comment: so i cant get in a dynamic way a path between to points ? becuse i have only pointone pointtwo and distance

Comment: I think what the asker means is that in example code for Dijkstra algorithms that he found, there are predefined arrays of points as part of the example. He seems not to know how to get data from the database instead. [Shahar](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1254257/shaharnakash): please post all the code: your entire DB connecting code, and the example you're working from that has hardcoded data. Someone can then do the modifications to demonstrate how to link the two. It'd be impossible to help you otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have the point and distance information, you can create a full graph (i.e. a graph where each node is connected to each other node) and run Dijkstra on this graph. This way you can find a shorter path between two nodes using intermediate nodes.

Please note that this is only useful / meaningful, if the distance is not a metric. Otherwise the direct connection between two points (i.e. their distance) is always smaller or equal to the distance using intermediate nodes.